# Digital scale 133.1 kg with $\Delta 100g$. How many significant digits does it have?

Tags: significant-figures, rounding-unit

Why do I ask this?
In a [video](https://youtu.be/fo_QOB65D7k?t=240) they discuss "Uncertainty in measurements"; just have to watch 2:30 minutes to get context.
For that they compare an analog with a digitial scale.
On the analog scale they say, that in 130 pounds 1,3 are certain and 0 is a uncertain digit (3 sigfigs).
Compared to that on the digital scale 133.6 pounds 1,3,3 are certain and 6 is uncertain (4 sigfigs).
They determine the position of the uncertain digit in the number of sigfigs as the decimal place, in which the result of $\frac{\Delta x}2$ lies.
They define $resolution=\frac{\Delta x}2$.
Now I get the following contradiction:
Intuitive resolution=0.1 pounds (display of digital scale).
Mathematical resolution=1 pounds
Why mathematical resolution 1 pounds?:
$\frac{1}{2}pounds$ is the decimal tenths place for the uncertain digit in the sequence of sigfigs.
I would than note a reading this way:
$133.6pound \pm 0.5pounds$ and this has 4 sigfigs.

To collect the communities opinion about this topic I had asked the following question instead:

---

If we have a digital scale, with 100g increments.
When we read 133.1 kg, does it mean that the true value is

$133.1 kg \pm 0.05kg$ or
$133.1 kg \pm 0.1kg$ or
$133.1 kg \pm 0.5kg$

I tend to the last guess, because the display resolution of 0.1 kg doesn't reflect the measure resolution of $\Delta x = 1 kg$.

If that guess is true, then the number of sigfigs is 4, isn't it?

So the rule is:

y is normalized notation!

Example with $y=0.5=5 \times 10^{-1}$.

$x \pm \frac{resolution}{2} = x \pm (y \times 10^t)$

and the #sigfigs is:

$\lceil{\log_{10}(\frac{x}{10^t})}\rceil$

Example: $\lceil{\log_{10}(\frac{133.1}{10^{-1}})}\rceil=4$

Thx in advance.

Comment: What's the fifth significant digit of 133.1? Any number you put next would be a complete guess.

Comment: With $100$g increments and no additional context, the second line is the value you can count on, because there is no information available to say where the cutoff is within that $100$g interval.

Comment: If there is no bias and hysteresis the measure is the first one. The comment by abiessu is wrong.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: "Any number you put next would be a complete guess". Isn't this just the definition of sig figs. The last sig fig is always uncertain. $s=s_1...s_{n-1}s_n$. But then the number of sig figs must be n=5. Is it really complete guess or at most 4? Because from 5 on it would round to position n-1.

Comment: @catweazle The .1 already is uncertain - the true value could actually be 133.09, or 133.11. A tenth of a kg is your measurement precision, so you can confidently say that the tenth-place digit is either 0 or 1. But the hundredths place digit could be anything from 0 to 9, and still fit with your measured value. The final significant digit can have some uncertainty, but it can't fail to provide any information at all. The hundredths place is below the resolution of your measurement tool.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: Then you agree to $133.1 kg \pm 0.1kg$? If you say that the hundredths place is arbitrary, then rounding doesn't take place. Therefore the interpretation for $133.1 kg \pm 0.1kg$ is: True value is in 133.00kg..133.199...kg and we just cutted of the hundredths place. 133.00kg is the -0.1kg edge and 133.199...kg is the +0.1kg edge of $133.1 kg \pm 0.1kg$. Right?

Comment: @catweazle I don't know how the scale rounds things off. The most likely case is that it's 133.1 plus or minus 0.05kg, but it could also be programmed to round down by dropping the hundreds place. Either way, it's not plus or minus 0.1kg, as that gives a precision of 0.2kg, not 0.1kg. If you can only state that the weight is between 133.1 and 133.3 kg, you don't have a scale that can measure to the nearest 0.1kg.